# Overall strategy for storing animated meshes

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to figure out how you'd take a mesh generated in a program like 3ds max and bring that into your game with animations, textures, etc.

I've looked at FBX and Collada, but from what I've read, they're used as an intermediate step between the modelling software and some final format that may be custom to the game.  What I'm looking for is a book or tutorial that would go over in a general way what you would store in your custom file, how you would store animation data, etc.

Right now I don't really have a general plan of attack and all of the guides I've seen stick to rendering a few triangles.

It doesn't have to be implementation specific to OpenGL, although that is what I'll be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Collada is an interchange format.
What that means is it is very much generic. And if I am right that is exactly what you are looking for!

You can use a library such as Assimp to load collada into a generic scene graph, and then have your game/renderer use it directly, or preprocess and then consume it.